# How can I efficiently generate a very large table of test data programmatically?

Tags: arrays, csv

## Goal:

- a .csv that populates 17 columns with a value 0-100 in increments of 5.
- The.csv should record all rows where the values in a row add up to exactly 100. (only and all combinations that add up to 100%)

For example, valid entries would be:

> START
>
> 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100
>
> 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,95
>
> 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,90
>
> ...
>
> 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100,0
>
> ...
>
> 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,20
>
> ...
>
> 100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>
> END

## Background, if relevant:

I'm currently using AutoIT to populate a .csv file for a machine learning test of index-based investment portfoios. Namely, testing every combination of 17 index funds against a model I've trained with some manually-created training data.

I'm starting to realize that the script I'm using might take weeks (or months) to finish. I let it run overnight and it's calculated billions of combinations, recorded 880K rows, and it's only used a third of the columns. I think the growth is exponential, so it's looking like this isn' a viable way to do this.

I don't mind using another method to generate the .csv file, but I'm sure there are better ways to do this so the file completes faster?

**Optimization in my AutoIT (SciTE) code or suggestions for a better tool are both welcome, I'm not a coder by profession and just have a basic understanding.**

## The code I'm currently using with AutoIT (SciTE editor) is here:

```
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "Terminate") ; press ESC to stop script
Func Terminate()
   Exit
EndFunc

Local $testnum = 0

Local $minFund = 1
Local $maxFund = 17
Local $increment = 5; fund percentage of portfolio to increment

; total stock market
Local $minTSM = 0
Local $maxTSM = 100
Local $TSM

; large cap blend
Local $minLCB = 0
Local $maxLCB = 100
Local $LCB

; large cap value
Local $minLCV = 0
Local $maxLCV = 100
Local $LCV

; large cap growth
Local $minLCG = 0
Local $maxLCG = 100
Local $LCG

; mid cap blend
Local $minMCB = 0
Local $maxMCB = 100
Local $MCB

; mid cap value
Local $minMCV = 0
Local $maxMCV = 100
local $MCV

; mid cap growth
Local $minMCG = 0
Local $maxMCG = 100
Local $MCG

; small cap blend
Local $minSCB = 0
Local $maxSCB = 100
Local $SCB

; small cap value
Local $minSCV = 0
Local $maxSCV = 100
Local $SCV

; small cap growth
Local $minSCG = 0
Local $maxSCG = 100
Local $SCG

; long term bond
Local $minLTB = 0
Local $maxLTB = 100
Local $LTB

; intermediate term bond
Local $minITB = 0
Local $maxITB = 100
Local $ITB

; short term bond
Local $minSTB = 0
Local $maxSTB = 100
local $STB

; treasury bills
Local $minBIL = 0
Local $maxBIL = 100
Local $BIL

; real estate
Local $minREIT = 0
$maxREIT = 100
Local $REIT

; commodities
Local $minCOM = 0
Local $maxCOM = 100
Local $COM

; gold
Local $minGLD = 0
Local $maxGLD = 100
Local $GLD

$TSM = $minTSM
While $TSM <= $maxTSM
   $LCB = $minLCB
   While $LCB <= $maxLCB
      $LCV = $minLCV
      While $LCV <= $maxLCV
         $LCG = $minLCG
         While $LCG <= $maxLCG
            $MCB = $minMCB
            While $MCB <= $maxMCB
               $MCV = $minMCV
               While $MCV <= $maxMCV
                  $MCG = $minMCG
                  While $MCG <= $maxMCG
                     $SCB = $minSCB
                     While $SCB <= $maxSCB
                        $SCV = $minSCV
                        While $SCV <= $maxSCV
                           $SCG = $minSCG
                           While $SCG <= $maxSCG
                              $LTB = $minLTB
                              While $LTB <= $maxLTB
                                 $ITB = $minITB
                                 While $ITB <= $maxITB
                                    $STB = $minSTB
                                    While $STB <= $maxSTB
                                       $BIL = $minBIL
                                       While $BIL <= $maxBIL
                                          $REIT = $minREIT
                                          While $REIT <= $maxREIT
                                             $COM = $minCOM
                                             While $COM <= $maxCOM
                                                $GLD = $minGLD
                                                While $GLD <= $maxGLD
                                                   $testnum = $testnum + 1
                                                   If $TSM + $LCB + $LCV + $LCG + $MCB + $MCV + $MCG + $SCB + $SCV + $SCG + $LTB + $ITB + $STB + $BIL + $REIT + $COM + $GLD = 100 Then
                                                      FileWrite("C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\predict.csv",$testnum & "," & $TSM & "," & $LCB & "," & $LCV & "," & $LCG & "," & $MCB & "," & $MCV & "," & $MCG & "," & $SCB & "," & $SCV & "," & $SCG & "," & $LTB & "," & $ITB & "," & $STB & "," & $BIL & "," & $REIT & "," & $COM & "," & $GLD & "," & @HOUR & ":" & @MIN &  ":" & @SEC & @CRLF)
                                                   EndIf
                                                   $GLD = $GLD + $increment
                                                WEnd
                                                $COM = $COM + $increment
                                             WEnd
                                             $REIT = $REIT + $increment
                                          WEnd
                                          $BIL = $BIL + $increment
                                       WEnd
                                       $STB = $STB + $increment
                                    WEnd
                                    $ITB = $ITB + $increment
                                 WEnd
                                 $LTB = $LTB + $increment
                              WEnd
                              $SCG = $SCG + $increment
                           WEnd
                           $SCV = $SCV + $increment
                        WEnd
                        $SCB = $SCB + $increment
                     WEnd
                     $MCG = $MCG + $increment
                  WEnd
                  $MCV = $MCV + $increment
               WEnd
               $MCB = $MCB + $increment
            WEnd
            $LCG = $LCG + $increment
         WEnd
         $LCV = $LCV + $increment
      WEnd
      $LCB = $LCB + $increment
   WEnd
   $TSM = $TSM + $increment
WEnd

Send ("COMPLETED")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints all 7.3 billion lines in around 6 minutes on a Mac. I have no idea how it will be useful to anybody :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){

   int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q;
   int p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12,p13,p14,p15; // partial sums
   unsigned long long lines=0;
   for(a=0;a<=100;a+=5){
    for(b=0;b<=100;b+=5){
     p0=a+b;
     if(p0>100)break;
     for(c=0;c<=100;c+=5){
      p1=p0+c;
      if(p1>100)break;
      for(d=0;d<=100;d+=5){
       p2=p1+d;
       if(p2>100)break;
       for(e=0;e<=100;e+=5){
        p3=p2+e;
        if(p3>100)break;
        for(f=0;f<=100;f+=5){
         p4=p3+f;
         if(p4>100)break;
         for(g=0;g<=100;g+=5){
          p5=p4+g;
          if(p5>100)break;
          for(h=0;h<=100;h+=5){
           p6=p5+h;
           if(p6>100)break;
           for(i=0;i<=100;i+=5){
            p7=p6+i;
            if(p7>100)break;
            for(j=0;j<=100;j+=5){
             p8=p7+j;
             if(p8>100)break;
             for(k=0;k<=100;k+=5){
              p9=p8+k;
              if(p9>100)break;
              for(l=0;l<=100;l+=5){
               p10=p9+l;
               if(p10>100)break;
               for(m=0;m<=100;m+=5){
                p11=p10+m;
                if(p11>100)break;
                for(n=0;n<=100;n+=5){
                 p12=p11+n;
                 if(p12>100)break;
                 for(o=0;o<=100;o+=5){
                  p13=p12+o;
                  if(p13>100)break;
                  for(p=0;p<=100;p+=5){
                   p14=p13+p;
                   if(p14>100)break;
                   for(q=0;q<=100;q+=5){
                    p15=p14+q;
                    if(p15>100)break;
                    if(p15==100){
                     lines++;
                     printf("%llu: %d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",lines,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q);
                    }
                   }
                  }
                 }
                }
               }
              }
             }
            }
           }
          }
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: 7.3 billion lines - that includes lines where the sum of the parts don't equal 100? This looks like it's written in C? (I haven't used C before)

Comment: It is in `C`, yes. It's one way to get some speed as it is compiled, rather than interpreted. The 7.3 billion lines is exclusively the ones where the columns add up to 100. I would send it to you but it's several GB!

Comment: I managed to set up a C environment on my Windows machine and got this to run. Works great, thank you!

Comment: follow-up: You weren't kidding. 273GB for 7.3B records. Interesting note: This took ~12.5 hours on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Well done for persevering! Not sure what toolchain you used, but for future reference `Debug` builds are slow, you might have done better with a `Release` build and optimisation turned on - but don't ask me how to do that in Windows.

Comment: I used http://www.mingw.org to get the environment set up, and only did 'gcc script.c' at the command line.  C is new to me, but I'll bet it defaults to DEBUG. It looks like I should have given it an -O3 or -Ofast flag: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html